# Fetch questions from database one by one onclicking next button and show the correct answer one by one

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="answer.php">   
      <?php 
      $email=$_SESSION['usr_id'];

      $res = mysqli_query($dbo,"select * from questions where email=' $email '") or die(mysql_error());
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);

     $i=1;
            while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){  
              ?>
                <?php if($i==1){?>         
                <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"></p>
                <input type="hidden"  name="qname<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $result['question'];?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" required value="<?php echo $result['opt1'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt1'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" required value="<?php echo $result['opt2'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt2'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" required value="<?php echo $result['opt3'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt3'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" required value="<?php echo $result['opt4'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt4'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                <br/>
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>
                </div>     

                 <?php }elseif($i<1 || $i<$rows){?>

                   <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"></p>
                <input type="hidden"  name="qname<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $result['question'];?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt1'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt1'];?>
               <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt2'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt2'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt3'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt3'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt4'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt4'];?>
                <br/>
                <br/><input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                <br/>
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Next</button>
                </div>





               <?php }elseif($i==$rows){?>
                <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"></p>  
                <input type="hidden" name="qname<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $result['question'];?>" > <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt1'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt1'];?>
               <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt2'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt2'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt3'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt3'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $result['opt4'];?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['opt4'];?>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                <br/>
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' name="submit" class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>
                </div>
      <?php } $i++;} 
      ?>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code displaying all the questions on the same page.
but i want to display question one by one.
Can some one help me with that what is wrong with script.It's not working.
This Html and all thing is working but script not working. I am not understanding what is wrong in this code.

```
 <script>
$('.cont').addClass('hide');
count=$('.questions').length;
 $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

 $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
     last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
     nex=last+1;
     $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

     $('#question'+nex).removeClass('hide');
 });

 $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
         last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
         pre=last-1;
         $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

         $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
     });        
</script>
```

Comment: u can use jquery. Put each question on a div and change the display when the button is clicked

Comment: time to debug your code

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is your friend on this. You can create several buttons and when the buttons are clicked, each question that is assign to this button is going to show the answer which is hide in first place. First hide all your elements when the page loads and then change them to show if the button is clicked

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#your_div_or_element_id').hide();
        $('#button_id').click(function(){
            $('#your_div_or_element_id').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to add at the very top of your script tag this $( document ).ready(function() {   and at the end of all your scripts this to close it });   if you dont add those lines the javascript will not load up see my example

Comment: I'am glad to hear that. :)